# Do while loops (Java)

Tags: java, do-while

Im trying to write a program to sum each digit of every 4 digit number. For example, I start with 1000 and once 1001 is added the thousands become 2, hundreds become 0, tens becomes 0 and units becomes 1. This should keep adding each number until it reaches 9999. This is my code, it just outputs 9999.

```
int num = 1000, unit = 0, ten = 0, hundred = 0, thousand = 0, newNum = 0, sumth = 0, sumh = 0, sumten = 0, sumu = 0;

while (num <= 9999)
{
    unit = num%10;
    newNum = num/10;
    ten = newNum%10;
    newNum=newNum/10;
    hundred = newNum%10;
    thousand = newNum/10;
    num++;
}
sumth = thousand + sumth;
sumh = hundred + sumh;
sumten = ten + sumten;
sumu = unit + sumu;

System.out.println(sumth + " " + sumh + " " + sumten + " " + sumu);
```

Comment: What is your question?  What do you expect it to output?

Comment: Something like :The sum of the units is 5
The sum of the tens is 10
The sum of the hundreds is 6
The sum of the thousands is 7
but i just have it all on one line for now

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where/how specifically does the observed behavior differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Tidying this up a little for readability:

```
int num = 1000,
    sumThousands = 0,
    sumHundreds = 0,
    sumTens = 0,
    sumUnits = 0;

    while (num <= 9999)
    {
        int units = num % 10;
        int tens = (num / 10) % 10;
        int hundreds = (num / 100) % 10;
        int thousands = (num / 1000) % 10;

        sumUnits += units;
        sumTens += tens;
        sumHundreds += hundreds;
        sumThousands += thousands;

        num++;
    }

System.out.println(sumThousands + " " + sumHundreds + " " + sumTens + " " + sumUnits);
```

The output you'll get is:

```
45000 40500 40500 40500
```

This is expected. For the sequence of integers 1000..9999:

- In the thousands column, every digit 1..9 is repeated 1000 times

  - So the thousands sum is `1000(9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1) = 1000(9(10)/2) = 45000`
- In every other column, every digit 0..9 is repeated 900 times

  - So the sums for the other columns are `900(9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1) = 900(9(10)/2) = 40500`

Answer (score 0):

It should be shifted inside `while loop`

```
while (num <= 9999)
    {
        unit = num%10;
        newNum = num/10;
        ten = newNum%10;
        newNum=newNum/10;
        hundred = newNum%10;
        thousand = newNum/10;

        sumth = thousand + sumth;
        sumh = hundred + sumh;
        sumten = ten + sumten;
        sumu = unit + sumu
        num++;    

    }
```

Output: `45000 40500 40500 40500`
Working link: https://ideone.com/WrAX8D

Comment: This makes them all the same number.

Comment: eg. if i have 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005
sum of thousands is 6, sum of hundreds is 0, sum of tens is 0, sum of units is 15... hope that makes sense